# Nifi error Wwth putsolrcontentstream processor

Tags: hadoop, solr, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

I am creating a flow of tweets using nifi and analyze them in solr but tweets coming into nifi but nothing happeing into solr.But error in nifi processor putsolrcontentstream could not connect to localhost:2181/solr cluster not found/not ready.

Putsolrcontentstream processor error:

[image]

Comment: You should show the code you are having problems with. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running in clustered mode?

I just set up a local (Standard mode) Solr core and in the **Solr Location** property I used `http://localhost:8983/solr/myDemoCore`. Might you be forgetting to mention the core's name?

If you haven't created a core:

`cd path/to/solr/bin/
./solr create -c myDemoCore
./solr restart`

Then use `http://localhost:8983/solr/myDemoCore` in the **Solr Location** property and try again.

Edit: I see that you're using Windows-- just change your path notation accordingly.